# Docker for Windows: Invoke-WebRequest fails on docker build

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, docker, dockerfile

I'm currently playing around with Docker for Windows on a Windows Server 2016. 
I wanna build a node.js image, but powershell is not able to connect to the remote server and download node.js.

This is the part in my Dockerfile which fails:

```
RUN ["powershell", "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://nodejs.org/dist/v7.4.0/node-v7.4.0-x64.msi -OutFile nodejs.msi"]
```

and I'm getting the following error:
[image: docker build error]

I'm behind a corporate proxy, but I've already configured the proxy and everything else like docker pull works.

Comment: This does appear to be a connectivity issue. Try adding -verbose to your invoke-webrequest command to see if that gives you more information. Perhaps the connection is being interrupted before it completes the download.

Comment: kind of wondering: why are you doing that instead of building `FROM node:6` or another base node image?